# c# Add/Remove Dynamic Plugins without restart

Tags: c#, plugins, architecture

I'm designing a solution that I believe will work well in a plugin style architecture.

The "Main Program" will provide services such as database access, messaging to remote clients, logging and other functions.

Each "Plugin" will be able to use those functions and contain custom functions that will perform "Plugin" specific logic.

**I need to be able to install and uninstall the plugins at runtime without the "Main Program" being restarted.** Uninstalls will mainly occur when new versions of the "Plugin" are available and need to be added to the "Main Program".

If I create each plugin as a DLL and place it in a folder I can signal the "Main Program" to load them and all is fine. What I'm not sure of is how to correctly unload them when no longer needed, without creating a memory leak.

If I do a Application.Load on the assembly the only way to unload it is to unload the whole AppDomain. I am not very familiar with how AppDomains work but this seems like it would cause issues.

Has anyone done this sort of thing before and can offer some advice on the best way to do this without creating instability or memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to load every plugin into its own AppDomain. There is no other way to make it unloadable. It doesn't make any memory leaks (if you don't make them yourself). And it is stable if you implement it right. It is not an easy task, but this topic is too big to explain in details, it would rather take a big article or a book.

Comment: That is what I thought. Was hoping there was a better way to do it, but sometimes the long road is better in the end I suppose.

Comment: @Kelly You can try to find a library for that. But MEF, most popular library for plugins, doesn't work with appdomains. And I almost sure there are some examples on Github.

Comment: Thanks I've used MEF a reasonable amount and your right it isn't exactly what I'm looking for here. I have plenty of time to snoop around and see what I can find.